# PHP preg_match: Multiple repetitions to one character class

Tags: php, preg-match

I'd like to allow multiple repetitions to one defined character class :).

```
$data = 'abc@abc-abc.abc';
echo preg_match('/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._-]+[a-z]+@+[a-z0-9]+[._-]?+[a-z0-9]+\.?+([a-z0-9]{2,})$/', strtolower($data)); // works (echo 1)

$data = 'abc@abc-abc.abc.abc';
echo preg_match('/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._-]+[a-z]+@+[a-z0-9]+[._-]?+[a-z0-9]+\.?+([a-z0-9]{2,})$/', strtolower($data)); // doesn't work (echo 0, but should return 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the dot inside a non capturing group `(?:` at the end and repeat that group as a whole 0 or more times using `*`

Use `+` instead of `*` if the part starting with the `.` or combined `[._-]` at the end should occur at least 1 time

```
^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._-]+[a-z]+@+[a-z0-9]+[._-]?+[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]{2,})+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5REcdh/1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :). Unfortunately abc@abc-abc.abc-abc.abc does not work. How can I solve that issue?

Comment: @ogm58191 Then you could use a character class matching either a dot or a hyphen `[.-]` for example `^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._-]+[a-z]+@+[a-z0-9]+[._-]?+[a-z0-9]+(?:[.-][a-z0-9]{2,})+$` https://regex101.com/r/qTEUjh/1

Comment: @ogm58191 If all parts after should start with 2 or more a-z0-9, you could shorten it to `^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._-]+[a-z]+@+[a-z0-9]{2,}(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*$`  https://regex101.com/r/au8QaV/1

Comment: Well done! But one last question :). How can I achieve that all emails with this format are valid too? name@a-b-c.com, name@a-b-c.a-b-c.com

Comment: Last domain (.com) must contain two letters :)

Comment: @ogm58191 In that case you might use `^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._-]+[a-z]+@+[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*$`  https://regex101.com/r/2SBVe9/1

Comment: Hi :), is it possible to allow one character before @? Like a@abc.com? And is it possible to count the characters before @ (max 64) and after @ (max 255)?

Comment: You could make what follows the first character class optional https://regex101.com/r/PUUpAg/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207000/discussion-between-ogm58191-and-the-fourth-bird).